# symfony 5 redireccionar con un id

Tags: php, symfony5

Intento redireccionar a la pagina donde muestro todos los usuarios de un grupo paso el id pero cuando lo intento no admite la url el código es el siguiente.
Lo que intento es que cuando cree un nuevo usuario me vuelva la vista de todos los usuarios de ese grupo pero me dice que la ruta no coincide

Con esto paso el id del grupo

```
<a href="/register/{{grupo.id}}">Crear nuevo alumno</a></br>
```

Con este código creo al usuario

```
/**
 * @Route("/register/{id}", name="app_register")
 */
public function register($id,Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $grupo=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Grupo::class)->find($id);
    $usuariosTotales= $grupo->getUsuariosTotales();
    $usuariosTotales++;
    //al ser un array toma la primera posicion 
    $rol=array("ROLE_USER");
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // encode the plain password
        $user->setPassword(
            $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
            )
        );

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user->setRoles($rol);
        $user->setGrupo($grupo);
        $grupo->setUsuariosTotales($usuariosTotales);
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        // do anything else you need here, like send an email
        //Aqui es donde seguramente este el fallo
        return $this->redirectToRoute("/grupo_alumnos/{$id}");
    }

    //<a href="{{ path('app_grupo_alumnos', {'id': grupo.id}) }}">Ver alumnos del grupo</a></br>

    return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
        'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Así creo al método que sacar a el grupo para sacar a los usuarios de este

```
/**
 * @Route("/grupo_alumnos/{id}", name="app_grupo_alumnos")
 */
public function grupo_alumnos($id,Grupo $grupo){
    $grupo=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Grupo::class)->find($id);
    //return $this->render('main/cuadrante.html.twig',[]);
    return $this->render('main/alumnado.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'MainController',
        'grupo' => $grupo
        
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes de usar path para poder pasarle los argumentos a la ruta

```
<a href="{{ path('app_register',{id:grupo.id}) }}">Crear nuevo alumno</a>
```

en donde el primer parámetro en path le pasa el name de la ruta, y en el segundo el identificador de la variable, posteriormente pasándole la variable